# Infinite loop in recursive program

Tags: python, recursion, fractals

i'm having an infinite loop in a recursive program that should not be here. My program is made to draw the Sierpinski triangle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle). Here is my code:

```
from Python32_Lja import*

init_window("Triangle de Sierpienski",600,600)
current_color(0,0,0)

A=[100,475]#A=[x1,y1]
B=[500,475]#B=[x2,y2]
C=[300,125]#C=[x3,y3]

def Sierpienski(A,B,C,n):

    if n==0:#On trace le triangle

        line(A[0],A[1],B[0],B[1])#AB
        line(B[0],B[1],C[0],C[1])#BC
        line(C[0],C[1],A[0],A[1])#CA

    else:

        MAB=[int((A[0]+B[0])/2),int((A[1]+B[1])/2)]#Milieu de AB
        MBC=[int((B[0]+C[0])/2),int((B[1]+C[1])/2)]#Milieu de BC
        MCA=[int((C[0]+A[0])/2),int((C[1]+A[1])/2)]#Milieu de CA

        line(MAB[0],MAB[1],MBC[0],MBC[1])
        line(MBC[0],MBC[1],MCA[0],MCA[1])
        line(MCA[0],MCA[1],MAB[0],MAB[1])

        A=MAB
        B=MBC
        C=MCA

    return(Sierpienski(A,B,C,n-1))

n=int(input("Entrez le nombre de profondeur : "))        
Sierpienski(A,B,C,n)

main_loop()
```

It's homework so there is some condition. The algorithm must be recursive, i need to use the Python32_Lja library (simplified Tkinter). I don't know why there is an infinite loop because the function return "n-1" that should end the program.

Comment: Have you debugged it? As in tried to figure out why it's wrong. You'll probably notice that the infinite loop makes sense if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your corrected version, you're only drawing the centre triangles. Try drawing each edge of the each triangle at each depth-layer, and the escaping from the recursion when you reach `n==0`:

```
def Sierpienski(A,B,C,n):

    if n==0:#On trace le triangle
        line(A[0],A[1],B[0],B[1])#AB
        line(B[0],B[1],C[0],C[1])#BC
        line(C[0],C[1],A[0],A[1])#CA
        return


    MAB=[int((A[0]+B[0])/2),int((A[1]+B[1])/2)]#Milieu de AB
    MBC=[int((B[0]+C[0])/2),int((B[1]+C[1])/2)]#Milieu de BC
    MCA=[int((C[0]+A[0])/2),int((C[1]+A[1])/2)]#Milieu de CA

    Sierpienski(A, MAB, MCA, n-1)
    Sierpienski(MAB, MBC, B, n-1)
    Sierpienski(C, MBC, MCA, n-1)


    return
```

Comment: I've just had a thought: your line-drawing should really be only at the lowest depth -- see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a base condition: you *always* return a recursive call with n-1, even if n is already 0. You should add a blank `return` inside the if block, so that it returns and terminates the recursion if n=0.

Alternatively, since the recurrence does not actually return anything, you might consider removing the return statements altogether, and just making the recursive `Sierpienski()` call inside the else block.

Comment: Thanks you sir but now it doesn't draw what it's supposed to draw.

Comment: Well @Paul, that is not a very helpful comment to make. I suggest you first try and figure it out and - if that does not work - come back with a detailled question. I believe your initial question was answered: a recursive function should always hit a terminating condition.